# looking to embed excel into html?

Tags: html, excel

I like the power of the pivot tables and was wondering if there is an easy way to embed excel sheets into the html for web?

If not, is there something similar on the web?

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel Web App and turn on interactivity. See this link for an example: http://datawiz.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/interactive-spreadsheets-in-html/
Let me know if it works for you.